# Node.js CLI application: Prevent exit from Ctrl + C and run async operation

Tags: node.js, shell

This question seems to have been asked a hundred times already, however I couldn't find a true solution so far. I have a Node.js application which does some network-related stuff. When the application exits from the user pressing Ctrl + C, I need to clean up some stuff on the server and therefore need to run several async network calls. I've tried a multitude of solutions but none seem to work properly -- the application always exits before any of those network requests are actually being made.

This is what I'm currently stuck with:

```js
async function exitHandler(callback: () => void) {
  Frp.stopFrp(printer);
  for (const config of frps) {
    await closeServerSession(config);
  }
  callback();
}

[
  'SIGHUP',
  'SIGINT',
  'SIGQUIT',
  'SIGILL',
  'SIGTRAP',
  'SIGABRT',
  'SIGBUS',
  'SIGFPE',
  'SIGUSR1',
  'SIGSEGV',
  'SIGUSR2',
  'SIGTERM',
].forEach(function (sig) {
  process.on(sig, function () {
    terminator(sig);
    printer.log('signal: ' + sig);
  });
});

function terminator(sig) {
  exitHandler(() => {
    printer.log('exitHandler has finished.');
    process.exit(1);
  });
  printer.log('Node server stopped.');
}
```

The loop in lines 3 to 5 is where the network requests should be made (`closeServerSession()` cleans up the session on the server for each of the sessions stored in the `frps` array).

When I try this and press Ctrl + C, I get the log with the signal (SIGINT) and immediately afterwards, the process exits. I however expect it to get "trapped" and only exit once the callback of the `exitHandler` has been called.

I do know of several command-line applications that can do exactly this -- run some long-lasting operations when the user presses Ctrl + C and only exit once these are done or if the user presses Ctrl + C again. So, there has to be some way to do this. How, though?